# Icons copyright

Tags: icons

Are icons from http://iconfinder.com/ free to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That will depend on the icon, when you click on the icon, you will see in the upper-left corner the license of the icon:

- Free for personal use
- Creative Commons (CC)
- ...

Answer (score 4):

From the site's own disclaimer page at http://www.iconfinder.com/about/disclaimer :

> Always check the license before using any icons and contact the author before using any icons commercially.

Comment: Commercially - like sell them? I just usr them at website, to make it a little nice to look. I do not sell them and do not use in any products to sell with.

Comment: Generally "commercially" is interesting to the creator/owner if you're making money with them somehow; regardless of whatever definition of "commercial" is used. :)

Answer (score 1):

By accepting these Terms of Use, you acknowledge and agree that all content presented to you on this site is protected by copyrights, trademarks, service marks, patents or other proprietary rights and laws, and is the sole property of IconFinder and/or its Affiliates. You are only permitted to use the content as expressly authorized by us or the specific content provider. Except for a single copy made for personal use only, you may not copy, reproduce, modify, republish, upload, post, transmit, or distribute any documents or information from this site in any form or by any means without prior written permission from us or the specific content provider, and you are solely responsible for obtaining permission before reusing any copyrighted material that is available on this site. Any unauthorized use of the materials appearing on this site may violate copyright, trademark and other applicable laws and could result in criminal or civil penalties.

Answer (score 0):

All icons are free to use, but some can only be used for personal purposes. So they are free as in "you don't have to pay", but that doesn't mean you own them and can do what you want.